# How to automatic callback UINavigationController's BackItem in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Like my question title , i need to callback `UINavigationController's` BackItem event without tap on `BackBarItem`.

I am using `UINavigationController` , i want to call these event automatic.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `popViewControllerAnimated:` method to programatically go back one step in a navigation controller:

```
[navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks you for your answer bro :) need to wait 10 minute to tick.

Comment: I have the same question, but popping is not the answer for me. That give me a wrong animation. Is there a way to call the action behind the backbutton (which gives me the correct animation)?